# Python Scrappy Xpath - can't extract selected data from table

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

i am trying to extract all the data of the attached table grouped by the country which containing the country name,
http://applications.slbfe.lk/jobbank/jsearchdisplay_an_m.asp?an=1712
i tried to execute

```
response.xpath('//div').xpath('.//tr[@bgcolor="#CCCCCC"]/td/b/font/text()').extract()
```

here i select the country name but how can i get all the data under this country name like Approved vacancy per country

[image: table]

Comment: i used scrapy shell, then i execute fetch command

fetch('http://applications.slbfe.lk/jobbank/jsearchdisplay_an_m.asp?an=1712')

Comment: i am using scrapy framework, no coding required to open the shell!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't shown your code how you have written to parse the tabular data, I gave a demo here to give you an idea how you can parse the selective data from a table. Just twitch the selectors in your code like i did here:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "http://applications.slbfe.lk/jobbank/jsearchdisplay_an_m.asp?an=1712"
res = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"lxml")
table = soup.select("table")[3]
for items in table.select('tr'):
    item_name = [' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select('td')[:3]] #this is where you change the index which column to parse
    print(' '.join(item_name))
```

Partial results:

```
Details Approved Vacancies Available Vacancies
Kuwait
House Boy 10 10
House Boy 10 8
House Cook - Male 10 10
House Cook - Male 10 8
```